# Patent # US 1152583 A

Tags: ownership, us1152583a

I am interested in knowing if the Whitesel family still owns this patent on the wire stretcher from 1915?

Comment: You could expect that the patent rights for a patent issued in 1915 to have been extinguished after 20 years.  Those rights are no longer owned.  I use a wire stretcher maintaining fences at home derived from [US 598,526](http://www.google.com/patents/US598526) see the image) with an improvement of chain mounted clamps for the wire ends, that patent issued in 1896 ([image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OcG4b.jpg)), also long expired.

Comment: @DavidKoontz You could post that, or at least the first two sentences of that (maybe more) as an answer.